# how to get min-date in angular material from another datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm quite new in coding and I have 2 date picker that want to set min date of second same as first one and if the second one choose become max date of first one in angular material
could any body have some ideas

**JS:**

```js
 angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('dateController', function dateController($scope) {
    $scope.myDate = new Date();
    $scope.minDate = new Date(
      $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.myDate.getMonth(),
      $scope.myDate.getDate()
    );
    $scope.myDate = null;
});
```

**HTML:**

```html
<md-input-container class="col-md-12" flex>
  <label>Check in</label>
  <md-datepicker 
    name="dateField"
    ng-model="ctrl.myDate" 
    md-min-date="minDate" 
    md-hide-icons="all" 
    ng-required="true"
    md-current-view="month"
    md-open-on-focus
    ng-messages>
  </md-datepicker>
  <div ng-messages="myForm.dateField.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>
```

appreciate for any idea and help

Comment: could you please explain more elaborately

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://forums.asp.net/t/2128200.aspx?Dynamically%20set%20minDate%20and%20maxDate%20on%20date%20picker%20angular%20js%20material) may provide the answer for this.

It basically has a `ng-change` handler (that you can set on each of the 2 datepickers) that will reset the model property bound to the `md-min-date` or `md-max-date` which will immediately be reflected in the datepickers.

Comment: Thanks for answer I out $wath an its working good for me:
`$scope.dayDate = new Date();
    
    $scope.$watch('dateFrom', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      $scope.minDate = newValue;
    });`

Comment: @JohnDoe, "$watch" should work too as it is for changes to the model as the UI field is bound to the model, "ng-change" is for changes via the UI, which I think is the main one we care in this scenario.